# How to say: If you do not have any income, please upload a letter stating that

Tags: word-choice

Is this worded correctly? Or should I say "stating as much"? It needs to sound professional but should also be easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative for 'stating.'

> [**verify**; **verifying**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verify)
>
> **1.**  to confirm or substantiate in law by oath
>
> **2.** to establish the truth, accuracy, or reality of

(Merriam-Webster online)

Comment: This is definitely from an American dictionary! The normal [British meaning](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/verify) is sense 2. Sense 1 would be *certify* or *testify* (although *verify* can be used it generally only applies to sworn affidavits).

Comment: Synonyms of *certify* and *testify*: "attest" or "afford evidence".